# Do vegans need to consider reduction in angiogenesis?

Tags: veganism, rawfood-diet

Polyphenols play a role in the reduction of inflammatory angiogenesis during cancer treatments, primarily administered as part of a diet (Mediterranean).

Do vegans, or people who follow other plant based diets, need to consider this as a potential hazard to injury recovery and muscle growth?

Since part of cancer treatment using polyphenols is to reduce angiogenesis in an attempt to prevent blood vessels from being developed specifically to feed the tumor. (ie... the tumor gives off signals to the body to divert angiogenic activity to the tumor, providing it with nutrients to grow as more blood vessels get "built" to supply the tumor).

So my logical conclusion is that plant based diets might have a negative effect on healthy people via reduction in angiogenesis when there is no need to reduce it (absence of cancer). Hence the question as my understanding is that polyphenols induce a general reduction in angiogenic activity and not localized to tumor signal disruption.

I have linked an review of a few studies, but there are many sources that have studied the effect of plant based or raw plant based diets as a means to help fight or prevent cancer via reduction in angiogenic activity.

https://www.spandidos-publications.com/10.3892/ijfn.2020.9

Why angiogenesis is important:

"Angiogenesis is the process by which new blood vessels form, allowing the delivery of oxygen and nutrients to the body's tissues. It is a vital function, required for growth and development as well as the healing of wounds."

From: [https://www.mskcc.org/news/what-angiogenesis#:~:text=Angiogenesis%20is%20the%20process%20by,as%20the%20healing%20of%20wounds](https://www.mskcc.org/news/what-angiogenesis#:%7E:text=Angiogenesis%20is%20the%20process%20by,as%20the%20healing%20of%20wounds).

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the site! I'm having a hard time understanding the question -- it may need more focus. You're asking about cancer treatment, cancer avoidance, muscle development, and injury recovery. That's pretty broad -- could you try focusing the question on one subject?

Comment: Much apologies, I have edited it. Let me know if it makes more sense now :)